# Камин загорался от лучины ровным пламенем. Ровным - определение?

Tags: сказуемые, определения

Камин **загорался** от лучины *ровным* **пламенем**?

Если пламенем - это часть сказуемого, то *ровным* разве может быть определением? Определение при сказуемом? Или это всё сказуемое - загорался ровным пламенем?
Или пламенем - это дополнение? Но загорелся (чем?) пламенем - как-то странно выглядит.

Answer (score 4):

Камин загорался от лучины ровным пламенем.

**Загореться пламенем, гореть пламенем** - это устойчивые выражения, единый член предложения (чем еще можно загореться?). Существует глагол запламенеть, но он используется редко [загораться ... пламенем | academic.ru](http://science_en_ru.academic.ru/3607/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F_..._%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC)

**Примечание.** Другой вариант предложения с тем же содержанием: Пламя в камине  от лучины начинало гореть ровно. **Ровное** пламя, пламя горит **ровно**. Распространителем является или определение, или обстоятельство образа действия.

Итак, сказуемое "загорелся пламенем". Слово "ровным" распространяет сказуемое, оно является **определением к слову "пламенем", входящему в сказуемое.**

Вообще говоря, сказуемое "загорался пламенем" использовано **именно для того, чтобы с помощью определения определить качество этого пламени.**

Сравнить: Камин загорался от лучины  пламенем. Убрали определение, и что получилось?

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Сама придумала это предложение, а как дошло дело до разбора, засомневалась. Уже давно у меня был вопрос, может ли ВЧ определение входить в состав сказуемого. Оказывается, может...

Answer (score 1):

Сказуемое здесь - *загорался*. Пламенем - дополнение.

Comment: Спасибо! А вообще от сказуемого же не может быть вопрос к определению, даже если сказуемое - существительное? Взрослые оказали бескорыстную помощь. Оказали бескорыстную помощь - всё сказуемое?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Оказали помощь.

>> *от сказуемого же не может быть вопрос к определению, даже если сказуемое - существительное?* Москва - первая столица России.